# How to make EditText have editable and not editable part Andorid?

Tags: android, text, properties, edit

I want to make an EditText in Android Studio which is username field . The text in the EditText is "email" and it is align in the right when you start typing the email the text "email" doesn't disappear and the entered email address is aligned in the left , like that:

http://postimg.org/image/z2niccg0n/

How to do that?

Comment: Add this in your edit text `android:gravity="right"` and for label use a text view

Comment: Is it possible to make it as in the picture or not?

Comment: Yes it is possible...

Comment: But doing it the way you say . It doesn't look exactly the same.

Comment: You will have to customize it. I just gave you a raw code to start with.

Answer (score 1):

Use something like this. Change other properties as per your need

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizotal" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:weight="0.25"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:text="EMAIL"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:layout_gravity="left"/>

<EditText 
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:weight="0.75"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:maxLines="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```